# ripple emulate error for phonegap android project

Tags: android, cordova, emulation, ripple

In my other computer I have ripple emulating a phonegap android app, but now I´m trying to emulate in my classroom pc and doesn´t work the hello world neither my project.

I have phonegap,npm,ant,java dk,android sdk and ripple-emulator installed.
When I go to:

mypath/platforms/android/assets/www
and type:
ripple emulate

this error happend:

> INFO: Server instance running on: localhost:4040 INFO: CORS XHR
>   proxy service on: localhost:4040/ripple/xhr_proxy INFO: JSONP
>   XHR proxy service on: localhost:4040/ripple/json_xhr_proxy
>   Cordova 3.0 project dected...
>
> **fs.js:654  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(pah)): Error: ENOENT, no such file or director "c:\mypath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution which is currently working on all platforms are based on some small source code tweaks. The major problem is regarding the www/platform folder. Especially older phonegap versions doesnt introduce the same Folder structure so you needto adjust the following file to make it properly:

Additional information:
Make sure ripple was installed globally as well as Phonegap and/or Cordova

```
npm install -g ripple-emulator
npm install -g phonegap
npm install -g cordova
```

This solution works for Linux, Mac and Windows. You only need to pay attention on the path. Filenames about the source code adjustments remain same. This explanation is based on windows but can be easily used for any other operating system.

1.) Find the ripple Folder on your hard Disk (on Windows you need to show your hidden files and than you should be able to find it at the following path:

Windows:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator
```

Pay attention to replace YOUR_USERNAME with your current username in the shown path. If you have customized your path where npm modules get installed please go to that folder and search for the following directory in it /ripple-emulator

2.) Next lets find the file which makes trouble to start ripple correctly. Within the /ripple-emulate directory navigate through the following subdirectories server\emulate. Full path e.g.

Windows:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate
```

3.) Open cordovaProject.js and replace all strings which contain "platforms" with an empty one "" as shown Bellow, you can also copy the code shown bellow...

```
var platforms = fs.readdirSync(path.join(paths.orig, ""));
        if (platforms.indexOf('android') >= 0) {
            opts.cordova = 'android';
            paths.android = path.join(paths.orig, "", "android", "assets", "www");
        }

        if (platforms.indexOf('ios') >= 0) {
            opts.cordova = 'ios';
            paths.ios = path.join(paths.orig, "", "ios", "www");
        }

        if (platforms.indexOf('firefoxos') >= 0) {
            opts.cordova = 'firefoxos';
            paths.firefox = path.join(paths.orig, "", "firefoxos", "www");
        }

        if (platforms.indexOf('blackberry10') >= 0) {
            opts.cordova = 'blackberry10';
            paths.blackberry = path.join(paths.orig, "", "blackberry10", "www");
```

4.) Now save it.

5.) Make sure you have uninstalled the ripple emulator plugin in chrome (to check open chrome browser, go to Settings and choose extensions). In case you don't know how to uninstall extensions in chrome you can find some additional instruction here https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113907?hl=en In addition make sure you are using chrome as your Default browser.

6.) Now open your command line and navigate to your phonegap specific www folder and run the command

```
ripple emulate
```

optional you also can run it with the following command:

```
ripple emulate --path/TO_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/www
```

Thank you & br
Schreda

Comment: A couple of lines above the code in list item 3 above is this `if(fs.existsSync(path.join(paths.orig, ".cordova")) || fs.existsSync(path.join(paths.orig, "config.xml")))`. That's how ripple detects that your project has the structure of PhoneGap 3.x. My project migrated through a couple of versions and didn't have this structure. Just make sure you either have .cordova directory or move your config.xml out to project root. After that, `ripple emulate --path www` works perfectly. During development, it's better to emulate from `www` because that it contains your latest touches.

Answer (score 1):

Try running ripple emulate from the *root* of the project, not in the platform www folder.

Comment: Most recent version of PG?

Comment: Maybe is this the problem? Can I install another phonegap version?

Comment: I'd install the latest for sure.